# Above the Fold Optimization - Should the Reset.css be inline too?

Tags: html, css, optimization

I was reading about the Above the Fold Optimization and it says that we should defer the css, so it can't block the render, and the CSS of the "first fold" of the page should inline, so you can prevent the Flash of Unstyled Content and prioritize loads (and Google Pagespeed Insights will be happy with your page).

But I was wondering, my reset.css is always on the code, and on the first Flash we can see the browser's default paddings and margins, and thus, breaking the page for a milisecond.

That means that my reset.css should be with all the inline from the first fold? Doesn't that make the css too big to be inline and bad for SEO and stuff?

Comment: Ehm... I've never seen a CSS file causing FOUF by itself. That's always caused by other resources loading (images, JavaScript doing AJAX etc). Are you sure that an external reset css file does that, even for a millisecond?

Comment: I think the idea is to put what you need inline, including the reset - but only the parts you need from the reset, not everything.